# Where am I going wrong in this modification for this Sql code?

Tags: sql, postgresql

my professor asked the class to modify the following code to be done using the *With* clause.

```
select dept_name, (select count(*) from instructor 
where department.dept_name = instructor.dept_name) 
as num_instructors from department;
```

This is what it prints out

```
  dept_name  | num_instructors
-------------+-----------------
 Civil Eng.  |               0
 Biology     |               2
 History     |               0
 Physics     |               2
 Marketing   |               4
 Pol. Sci.   |               3
 English     |               4
 Accounting  |               4
 Comp. Sci.  |               2
 Languages   |               3
 Finance     |               1
 Geology     |               1
 Cybernetics |               4
 Astronomy   |               1
 Athletics   |               5
 Statistics  |               6
 Psychology  |               2
 Math        |               0
 Elec. Eng.  |               4
 Mech. Eng.  |               2
(20 rows)
```

I have been able to modify the code except my num_instructors are all value 50. I have tried playing around with it, but I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Can you give me suggestions on how to fix this?

This is my code.

```
with dept(dept_name) as (select dept_name from department),
dept_count(num_instructors) as (select count(*) 
from department, instructor 
where department.dept_name = instructor.dept_name) 
select dept_name, num_instructors from dept, dept_count;
```

And this is my output.

```
  dept_name  | num_instructors
-------------+-----------------
 Civil Eng.  |              50
 Biology     |              50
 History     |              50
 Physics     |              50
 Marketing   |              50
 Pol. Sci.   |              50
 English     |              50
 Accounting  |              50
 Comp. Sci.  |              50
 Languages   |              50
 Finance     |              50
 Geology     |              50
 Cybernetics |              50
 Astronomy   |              50
 Athletics   |              50
 Statistics  |              50
 Psychology  |              50
 Math        |              50
 Elec. Eng.  |              50
 Mech. Eng.  |              50
(20 rows)
```

Comment: On a side note: Please don't use comma-separated joins (`from department, instructor`). They are a relict of the 1980s and made redundant in 1992 with the introduction of explicit joins in SQL (`from department inner join instructor on ...`).

Comment: I've corrected your tags, removing *database*, adding *sql*. You have a question regarding **SQL** (how to write a query in SQL); you don't have a question on **databases** (e.g. regarding normalization or how to represent m:n relations in a database, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

I am adding this to explain what's wrong with your own query.

First of all

```
from department, instructor 
where department.dept_name = instructor.dept_name
```

is the ancient syntax for

```
from department
inner join instructor on department.dept_name = instructor.dept_name
```

(You are combining each instructor row with its department row here.)

And this alone

```
from dept, dept_count
```

is the ancient syntax for

```
from dept
cross join dept_count
```

(You are creating all possible combinations of departments and department counts here. With 20 departments and 20 department counts you would create 20 x 20 = 400 result rows for instance.)

Your subquery

```
select count(*) 
from department, instructor 
where department.dept_name = instructor.dept_name
```

adds the department row to each instructor first (with 20 departments and 50 instructors you'd get 50 result rows) and then you count them. The result is a single row with the total number of instructors (50 in the example). This is so because you are saying "count the instructors" in that query, rather than "count the instructors *per* department" which would translate to `GROUP BY dept_name`.

In your main query you are doing this:

```
from dept, dept_count
```

which means you combine every department row with the row that contains the total count.

Answer (score 1):

In your query there is a subquery in the `SELECT` clause. For each result row, it selects the number of instructors for the department in question.

Now you are supposed to move this to the `FROM` clause. There is no longer *one* department you are dealing with, then. You want the count *per* department:

```
select dept_name, count(*)
from instructor
group by dept_name;
```

If you see it guaranteed that there is at least one instructor per department, or you decide not to show departments without instructors, then you'll use an `INNER JOIN`, otherwise you'll use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

**Inner join:**

```
select d.dept_name, i.num_instructors
from department d
inner join
(
  select dept_name, count(*) as num_instructors
  from instructor
  group by dept_name
) i on i.dept_name = d.dept_name;
```

(In this particalar example where the instructor table already contains all you need, it would even suffice to reduce the whole query to the subquery. It already contains the final result. No need to join the department table.)

**Outer join:**

```
select d.dept_name, coalesce(i.instructors, 0) as num_instructors
from department d
left outer join
(
  select dept_name, count(*) as instructors
  from instructor
  group by dept_name
) i on i.dept_name = d.dept_name;
```

As you see, we must deal with the possibility that the subquery returns no row for a department, so we must turn the resulting null count into a zero.

Using a `WITH` clause merely means moving a subquery from the `FROM` clause to the beginning of the query, either for readability or in order to use it more than once in the query:

```
with i as
(
  select dept_name, count(*) as instructors
  from instructor
  group by dept_name
)
select d.dept_name, coalesce(i.instructors, 0) as num_instructors
from department d
left outer join i on i.dept_name = d.dept_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a with clause for this, but there is no need.

The simplest query would be

```
select department.dept_name, count(instructor.dept_name) as num_instructors
from department
left join instructor on department.dept_name = instructor.dept_name
```

If you want to add a with clause you could add:

```
;with counts as (
    select department.dept_name, count(instructor.dept_name) as num_instructors
    from department
    left join instructor on department.dept_name = instructor.dept_name 
) 
select * from counts
```

Comment: You are right, simply outer joining the instructors table and then aggregating the resulting rows, is a good way to write this query. Generally though, I prefer aggregating before joining. This does make such queries a tad more complicated, but lets you easily extend the query (e.g. adding the average room size calculated from a rooms table to it).